# Different addresses for different products

Tags: php, seo

I have a table shoes(id,shoename,color,brand,price,imagename,available). I am trying to sell shoes online through my website. Currently what's happening is, catalog.php(a page on my website) shows all the shoes in my table 'shoes'. Here's the code in inside a loop.

```
echo "<div class='shoe-view'>";
 echo "<img class='show-view-image' src='scripts/shoes/uploads/".$result["imagename"]."' alt='".$result["imagename"]."'/>";
 echo "<form action='viewshoe.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<button value='".$result["id"]."' name='messagebutton' class='send-message'>View Shoe</button>";
  echo "<input value='".$result["shoename"]."' name='shoename' type='hidden'/>";
 echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
```

With every shoe, there is a button view shoe and this button directs to viewshow.php(Another page on my website) Which shows all the details about the shoe. Here's how it looks like :

```
 echo "<div class='shoe-view'>";
  echo "<img class='show-view-image' src='scripts/shoes/uploads/".$result["imagename"]."' alt='".$result["imagename"]."'/>";

  echo "<p class='sub-heading desc catalogfont' style='color:rgb(184, 55, 60);'>".$result["shoename"]."</p>";
  echo "<p class='content catalogfont' style='font-weight:bold;'>".$result["price"]."</p>";
  echo "<p class='content catalogfont' style='font-weight:bold;'>".$result["Color"]." : ".$result["brand"]."</p>";
  echo "<form action='buyshoe.php' method='post'>";
   echo "<button value='".$result["id"]."' name='messagebutton' class='send-message'>Buy Shoe</button>";

  echo "</form>";
 echo "</div>";
```

Here's my question: E-Commerce websites like flipkart.com have different address for each product on their site. 
Visit http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/casual-shoes/pr?sid=osp%2Ccil%2Ce1f&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_men_0_Casual+Shoes and see all items will have a different address when you open a product. This practice is good for sharing a product and in Search Engine Optimization. I am not sure how do i get a different address for each of my products. Do I make a different php(eg shoe1.php) file during upload and use viewshoe.php to redirect to my shoe1? Because currently all my shoes have a single address, viewshoe.php.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel while there are so many open source webshop solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with using the `$_GET` query string variables in PHP? You would simply do this:

```
echo '<a href="shoepage.php?shoe_id='.$result['id'].'">'.$result['shoename'].'</a>';
```

Then on `shoepage.php` fetch the shoe from the database with the matching ID. For better SEO, you would no doubt want to use the shoe's name (probably normalized to be URL friendly, like `?shoe=funky-seven-shoes`) instead of the database ID; create a new column for those.

For even more SEO, you'll want to look at URL rewriting (using `.htaccess` & `mod_rewrite`) to get URLs like `/shoe/funky-seven-shoes` that map to `shoepage.php?shoe=funky-seven-shoes` etc. Here's an example .htaccess rewrite rule (presuming your shoe URL identifiers only have characters `a-z, A-Z, 0-9`, underscores and dashes, modify as needed):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^shoe/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ shoepage.php?shoe=$1
```

You can also use method GET instead of POST in your forms to have the query string visible in the address bar. GET is the recommended method for all requests that don't explicitly request a change in the server/database state (ie. insert, update or delete).

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am familiar with the $_GET query strings in php, What I wasn't familiar with was mod_rewrite! Thanks again.

Comment: @user3783952 happy studies. I've added in a sample .htaccess file that does the rewriting. If you want to add categories etc. into the URL, then you need to craft on some more; like `RewriteRule ^shoe/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ shoepage.php?category=$1&shoe=$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is all kinds of wrong, but to answer your question: Don't post your shoe id to `viewshoe.php`, use GET instead; and use server rewrite rules to rewrite the URLs.

So, for example, a shoe may be at `example.com/viewshoe.php?id=big-red-shoe`. Using the following .htaccess rewrite rule you'll be able to access the shoe at `example.com/shoes/big-red-shoe`.

```
RewriteRule ^shoes/([^/]*)/?$ /viewshoe.php?id=$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the right kind of approach in implementing such systems?

Comment: To start with, reinventing the wheels is rarely a good idea. There are lots of open source systems that will do just this. Some things that jumped out at me are: you don't appear to be separating presentation from business logic; a single entry point for your system would be more appropriate; as would using some sort of router to route to your page controllers; and, of course, it would be better to use HTTP they way it was intended. If you're interested, I can point you in the right direction for some good reading.